# Order of variables changes estimated coefficients in glmnet

Tags: r, glmnet

I am working with the glmnet package in R and came across a problem when trying to reproduce an "old" classifier. If the explanatory variables are permuted (say in reverse order), the resulting coefficients from cv.glmnet are not equal to the coefficients using the unpermuted design matrix.

For example, consider the following data:

```
library(glmnet)
set.seed(1)

#Set initial parameters
n <- 100
p <- 1000

#Simulate data
x <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), nrow = n, ncol = p)
colnames(x) <- as.character(1:p)
beta <- rnorm(n = p, mean = 2, sd = 2)
beta[rbinom(p, size = 1, prob = 0.5) == 0] <- 0
y <- x %*% beta + rnorm(100, sd = 0.1)
```

Then run glmnet with the LASSO penalization (alpha = 1) for both the design matrix x and the permuted version of x.

```
#Set parameters for cross validation with cv.glmnet
lambda <- exp(seq(-1, 1, length.out = 100))
alpha <- 1
foldid <- rep(1:10, each = 10)

#Run cross validation
fit <- cv.glmnet(x = x, y = y, family = "gaussian", alpha = alpha, 
             lambda = lambda, 
             foldid = foldid)

#Save coefficients
coef1 <- as.matrix(coef(fit, s = "lambda.min"))

#Run cross validation with rearranged design matrix
order <- ncol(x):1
fit2 <- cv.glmnet(x = x[,order], y = y, family = "gaussian", alpha = alpha, 
              lambda = lambda, 
              foldid = foldid)

#Save coefficients
coef2 <- as.matrix(coef(fit2, s = "lambda.min"))
coef2 <- coef2[rownames(coef1),]
```

Then compare the coefficients, the cross validation error, and the linear predictors.

```
> summary(coef2 - coef1)
       1             
 Min.   :-0.2738963  
 1st Qu.: 0.0000000  
 Median : 0.0000000  
 Mean   : 0.0003739  
 3rd Qu.: 0.0000000  
 Max.   : 0.3643040

> min(fit$cvm)
[1] 4584.373
> min(fit2$cvm)
[1] 4596.626

> summary(cbind(1,x) %*% coef2 - cbind(1, x) %*% coef1)
       1          
 Min.   :-0.5100  
 1st Qu.:-0.1613  
 Median : 0.0210  
 Mean   : 0.0000  
 3rd Qu.: 0.1333  
 Max.   : 0.6139
```

For all three measures, we see a difference between the models while only the order of the variables has been changed. Can anybody explain this?

Comment: You might get some insight by studying how the results vary as `p` increases from $1$ to $1000$ (and greater).  It would help to examine statistics about the accuracy of the estimates, too.

Comment: Does the problem still exist if you let glmnet choose it's own sequence of lambdas?

Comment: No, by letting glmnet choose its own lambda sequence, the coefficients become identical! Can you explain why this is the case?